# How to unit test a new Keycloak Authenticator?

Tags: unit-testing, keycloak

I extended the `UsernamePasswordForm` authenticator that comes with Keycloak. I was looking for examples on how to "unit" test it.

Does anyone have an examples?
Or maybe point me somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine ended up doing this work for me. His strategy was simple but it's annoying at the same time.

```
public abstract class KeycloakTestBase {
    protected final KeycloakSession session = mock(KeycloakSession.class);
    protected final HttpRequest request = mock(HttpRequest.class);
    protected final RealmModel realm = mock(RealmModel.class);
    protected final UserProvider userProvider = mock(UserProvider.class);
    protected final UserCredentialManager userCredentialManager = mock(UserCredentialManager.class);
    protected final EventBuilder eventBuilder = mock(EventBuilder.class);
    protected final ThemeProvider themeProvider = mock(ThemeProvider.class);
    protected final Theme theme = mock(Theme.class);
    protected final KeycloakContext context = mock(KeycloakContext.class);

    protected KeycloakTestBase() {
        when(session.userLocalStorage()).thenReturn(userProvider);
        when(session.userCredentialManager()).thenReturn(userCredentialManager);
        when(session.getContext()).thenReturn(context);

        when(context.getRealm()).thenReturn(realm);

        when(realm.getLoginTheme()).thenReturn("ourtheme");

        when(eventBuilder.user(anyString())).thenReturn(eventBuilder);

        when(userProvider.getUserById(anyString(), eq(realm))).thenReturn(getRandomUser());

        when(session.getProvider(ThemeProvider.class, "extending")).thenReturn(themeProvider);

        try {
            when(themeProvider.getTheme(anyString(), any(Theme.Type.class))).thenReturn(theme);
            when(theme.getMessages(any(Locale.class))).thenReturn(new Properties());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected UserModel getRandomUser() {
        return spy(new InMemoryUserAdapter(session, realm, UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
    }
}
```

Afterward used this as a base for writing new unit tests. This base class takes care of wiring up most things together and returning some sane defaults.

The difficulty in unit testing classes that extend base keycloak classes is that occasionally you'll run into some static methods being called in the keycloak code. If you're lucky you can remove the static code and pass it in as a dependency. If you're unlucky......then you're unlucky. Haven't run into the unlucky case yet though. For example, we have this `AuthenticationManagerHelper` to alleviate the call to the static `AuthenticationManager` class.

```
public class AuthenticationManagerHelper {

    public AuthenticationManager.AuthResult authenticateIdentityCookie(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, boolean checkActive) {
        return org.keycloak.services.managers.AuthenticationManager.authenticateIdentityCookie(session, realm, checkActive);
    }
}
```

Comment: As Keycloak has recently moved to Quarkus, there may be a chance that this will be possible using `QuarkusTest`, which would mean automated testing within a running Keycloak. I tried to start a discussion on this here:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/11841#discussion-4053401